# At which SE site should a question about specific online compiler service features be asked?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

What Stack Exchange site is the best place to ask the following question?

> Does there exist an online compiler (that includes C++11) that let's
>   you type into a terminal-like window?
>
> All of the online compilers I have found so far have a box where you
>   can type in all of your input, but I am looking for something that I
>   can type in input, line by line.

I don't think it's fit for Stack Overflow, so which Stack Exchange site, if any exists, is this question fit for?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but this seems to be an extremely low researched question either way. There are plenty of such online compilers to find, and most SE sites reject to ask questions to find 3rd part resources.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ῥεῖ I've tried looking for a very long time, and I haven't found a single one. All the ones I find like ideone.com have an input stream that you type in all at once. Not one at a time like a terminal.

Comment: As far for the c++ and c language´families: http://cpp.sh/ 1st hit.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what about for other languages? Sorry if I seem too uptight, I'm just trying to find a good online compiler. I apologize for this.

Comment: You may try at [SE Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but be sure to meet the site's policies.

Comment: You would need to explain why it has to be online. Free compilers are available for most languages, and certainly for C++. If you are looking to skin someone else's service, that would almost certainly be off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a site called [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) but they have *very specific* requirements found [here](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) in addition to the [how to ask](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. It would be best to read them before positing on that site. You have to include some very specific details in your post describing your operating system and the specifics of the application you require.